# Importing PHP code in Joomla Component development

Tags: php, joomla, custom-component, require-once

Can't figure out how to import php files into my joomla component- all of these fail:

- require_once('code.php');
- require_once(dirname(**FILE**).DS.'code.php');
- require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'code.php' );

Any ideas?  thanks

Comment: How do they fail? Do you get any error messages? Try writing the path you think you're accessing to the error log: error_log(JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'code.php'). This will write tne evaluated path to your error log; it may turn out that it's not what you think it is. I've used require_once( JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'reportHelpers.php'); where reportHelpers.php is in the same directory as the file I'm using the require_once in.

Answer (score 2):

require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT_SITE.'/path/inside/your/component/folder.php');

Also - don't use DS - it is deprecated in Joomla 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Try jimport, see Joomla's docs on this: http://docs.joomla.org/Jimport

```
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');
```

This will include the php file "/libraries/joomla/application/component/controller.php".

Comment: This is for joomla base libraries, found in the root joomla directory.  I'm need php code that is part of my custom component, in my component directory.

Answer (score 0):

Usually these are included in a helper.php file

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/helper.php';
```